# CMake error: 'target is not built by this project' Clion Kotlin

Tags: opencv, cmake, kotlin, opencv3.0

I'm trying to load OpenCV Libraries in `CMakeFile.txt` but it always ends with this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:21 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "HelloWorld" which is not built by
  this project.
```

I've searched on the Internet but have got no solution.

```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

   set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/KotlinCMakeModule)

   project(untitled1 Kotlin)

   find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)


   IF (OpenCV_FOUND)
      include_directories(/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.0_1/include)
      link_libraries(/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.0_1/lib)
   ENDIF(OpenCV_FOUND)


  konanc_executable(
        NAME HelloWorld
       SOURCES hello.kt
  )

  target_link_libraries(HelloWorld
         /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.0_1/lib
         )
```

Someone can help me? I think it's not working because on the use of `konanc_executable` instead of `add_executable` but I need to use Kotlin so I cannot use the `add_executable` command.

Comment: Not an expert in kotlin, but the [first definition](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlinconf-spinner/blob/master/kotlin-native/samples/fullstack/KotlinCMakeModule/CMakeKotlinInformation.cmake#L162) of function `konanc_executable` I have found, uses `${KONANC_NAME}.kexe` as the target name of the "actual" executable. In you case the target name would be `HelloWorld.kexe`. Not sure whether you may link the executable with a "native" library, but you may try.

Comment: No more errors but I'm not quite sure it's ok because it gives me: WARNING: Target "HelloWorld.kexe" requests linking to directory "/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.0_1/lib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.

Comment: Yes, the warning is correct: you need to link (`link_libraries`) with **libraries** (`.a`, `.so` or other files), not with *directories*.